Laravel services, should we inject model classes or just use them with imports?
I started refactoring a Laravel app that has most of its logic in controllers, into services. I do not plan on using the repository pattern.
When using a model in a service class which is the better way?

Importing the model and using it directly eg.:
User::all()

Injecting it in the constructor of the service and using it like this:
$this->userModel->all()



Since you are not going to use repository, then use it directly via import.
As I understand it, services is used to handle business logic and repository is used to handle model data. In less complex systems, you can use services directly, and then when you need model data, new the corresponding model. It's that simple.

You can use any of the stated options since you mentioned this

I do not plan on using the repository pattern.

But even if you were to use repository patterns it is not recommened to

Injecting it in the constructor of the service and using it like this:

Because it violates the D(i.e Dependency Inversion Principle) of SOLID principal which state that ....
High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules, but rather both should depend on abstractions.
And to achieve abstraction you need to create a interface that will implemented by a Solid-class which will implement the bussiness logic. And then you can inject that solid-class to the constructor of the Service-class.
In this way the two module gets loosely coupled as well as it also maintain SOLID principles.
In a large-scale system & complex project you should maintain this approach no matter which framework/language you use.
